# How to upload images on Facebook wall by using MVC3, C#?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to upload photos into Facebook by using MVC3 C#. The code is running successfully but the photos are not uploaded into Facebook. I'm having add ID and App Secret. I tried many ways and for many days I worked hard, but the result is zero. Here is the code of my controller

[HttpPost][HttpGet]

```
public ActionResult Profile(HttpPostedFileBase file, FacebookOAuthResult facebookOAuthResult) {
  dynamic args = new ExpandoObject();
  args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
  args["message"] = "hi";
  args["picture"] = "http://apps.facebook.com/Uploads/photos";
  string accesstoken=FacebookWebContext.Current.AccessToken;
  FacebookClient fbApp = new FacebookClient(accesstoken);
  try {
    fbApp.Post("MYAPPID" + "/Photos", args);
  } catch (FacebookOAuthException ex) {
            //
  }
  // Verify that the user selected a file
  if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0) {
    var path1 = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/uppoads"), file.FileName);
    //file.SaveAs(path1);
    fbApp.Post("MYAPPID" + "/photos", path1);
  }
  // redirect back to the index action to show the form once again
  return RedirectToAction("Profile");
}
```

Could anyone help me to find the solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are Post the local path of the photo to Facebook, FB doesn't know what it is.
You should post the photo as binary in the Post body.

```
var media = new Facebook.FacebookMediaObject();
var filebytes  = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path1);
media.SetValue(filebytes);
fbApp.Post("248050331932489" + "/photos", media);
```

Comment: could you please send complete code for this controll and .cshtml

Comment: How can i pass these images on facebook wall from button field

Comment: finally i'm succeed to upload images to facebook from my mvc3 app